# "You don't have permission to upload files" - AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to upload a video to AWS S3 bucket.
Uploading smaller file as in PDF / txt - works.
Each time uplaoding a video brings this error:
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgNbo.png)

Tried different videos + different bucket policies.
Also tried to upload it public / private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AWS documentation:

For large files, Amazon S3 might separate the file into multiple uploads to maximize the upload speed. The Amazon S3 console might time out during large uploads because of session timeouts. Instead of using the Amazon S3 console, try uploading the file using the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI) or an AWS SDK.

Here is the link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-large-file-uploads/

Comment: Thanks - it works - and even faster than browser upload. Much appreciated.